# Webpack - how to rerun the config on watch update in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

using Webpack v5 where have a function inside webpack.config.ts that generates something on first build and then saves it into process.env. I need this function to be run every time I make some changes inside the app's code (and save ofc). However, while the dev mode reacts to all other changes I make, it doesn't run the function inside the config. Any way to change that and make sure the config is reinintialized on saved changes?

In my package.json, I run the dev server with `"dev": "webpack serve --mode development"`

I've tried both *watch: true* attribute in the config and *webpack-watch-files-plugin*, but none helped with this.